# Why does MinGW's stdio.h file cause syntax errors?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, mingw

I have a C project in Eclipse compiling with MinGW on Windows 7.  I am getting what appear to be syntax errors originating outside my project in stdio.h:

```
c:\mingw\include\stdio.h:345:12: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '__mingw__snprintf'
 extern int __mingw_stdio_redirect__(snprintf)(char*, size_t, const char*, ...);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\stdio.h:349:12: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '__mingw__vsnprintf'
 extern int __mingw_stdio_redirect__(vsnprintf)(char*, size_t, const char*, __VALIST);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The compile command is

```
gcc -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -DprojCOVERAGE_TEST=0 -O0 -g3 -Wall -Wextra -c 
-fmessage-length=0 -Wcast-qual -o "Interface.o" "Interface.c"
```

I would like to understand what is causing these errors in order to compile without editing stdio.h.

Comment: Can you show your `Interface.c` file (or rather a shorter file that also includes `stdio.h` and produces the same error message when compiled)?

Comment: Please show a minimal file `Interface.c` that can be used to reproduce the problem on your system.

Comment: The issue is very likely with code (or a header) appearing *before* your `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: To diagnose in any detail, we need a [mcve] demonstrating the issue.

Comment: You probably have a missing `;` or `{` or `}` in your `.h` code. It's hard for the compiler to find the exact line sometimes; especially in headers.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  The problem seems to have been fixed by including stdio.h before the problem code.

Comment: Unsure of the protocol for Stack Overflow... If the problem has been solved this quickly should I delete the question or mark it answered?

Comment: If it is just a simple typo you can go ahead and delete the question. Be careful not to delete too many of your own questions when you are new though, the site might think that you are trying to vandalize your own content if you do it too often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by stdio.h being included in the wrong place.  Including it at the beginning of the file fixed the issue.